# how to fill a Pandas dataframe column with a list containing string values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with 142 rows.
I have created a new column. I want to fill this new column with a list containing strings.

```
my_list = ['abc','def','hig']
df['names'] = df['names'].fill(my_list) #pseudo code
```

I want to fill all the 142 rows in 'names' column with string values in the list in the same order.

```
The output should be as:   

     names
   1 abc
   2 def
   3 hig
   4 abc
   5 def
```

Comment: you want all 142 rows filled with this list? so `df['names']=[['abc','def','hig']]*len(df)` ?

Comment: I think so @anky_91

Comment: have you tried df['names'] = list ?

Comment: I mean with string values inside the list.first value in the list should be assigned to first row,second value to second row and so on.

Comment: I also thought about this @anky_91 Bit i think, there Must be a Better Solution

Comment: @EduardoSousa that wouldnt fit in to all 142 rows does it?

Comment: Sidenote, try to avoid using reserved names for your variable, don,t use `list`, instead something like `my_list`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need something like below withh `np.resize` which will resize the list according to the dataframe.

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5,4)),columns=list('ABCD'))

    A   B   C   D
0  10  99   0  61
1  55   0  52  53
2  34  88  79  54
3  25  32   1  89
4  39  30  77   5
```

Solution:

```
mylist=['abc','def','hig']
df['names'] = np.resize(mylist,len(df))
print(df)
```

---

```
    A   B   C   D names
0  10  99   0  61   abc
1  55   0  52  53   def
2  34  88  79  54   hig
3  25  32   1  89   abc
4  39  30  77   5   def
```

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it.  Try this,

```
import pandas as pd
list = ['abc','def','hig']
df=pd.DataFrame(list)
df.columns=['names'] #provides a name for the column

df_repeated = pd.concat([df]*48, ignore_index=True)
```

which gives you 48*3=144 rows.  Then,

```
df_repeated =df_repeated.reindex(df_repeated.index.drop(144)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: ahhh.  Ok, let me think on it.

Answer (score 2):

just assign the list to the column like so; it will simultaneously create the column called 'names' and fill it with the list :

```
df['names'] = my_list
```