# Can't fill a specifc cell of a Dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill an specif cell in Pandas with a string.
The previous value of this specific cell is a NaN.
The command I'm using is:

```
value = "banana"    
mask = df_nf_rejeitados["NF"] == key
index = df_nf_rejeitados[mask].index
df_nf_rejeitados[mask].loc[index, "OBS ARQ RETS - LOTES"].fillna(value, inplace=True)
```

Pandas is not rising an an error of any kind, he is just not changing the value for me.
If I print:

```
print(self.__df_nf_rejeitados[mask].loc[index, "OBS ARQ RETS - LOTES"])
```

He will just return the index of row and the value NaN. Like this:

```
20: NaN
```

I have no idea why this would be wrong. Anyone can help me to spot the problem, please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure that this `NaN` is a real nan and not a string that says `"NaN"` ?

Comment: Yeah... I didn't check that. Good idea. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Solve my problem with this link: [how to fill a Pandas dataframe column with a list containing string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827464/how-to-fill-a-pandas-dataframe-column-with-a-list-containing-string-values)

It's not the exactly thing that I was looking for but did the job very well for me.